# Does WinCE SDK support WinHttp?

Tags: sdk, windows-ce

According to [TCP/IP Support in Windows CE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms884969.aspx) it should support WinHttp. But after installing SDK I cant find Winhttp.h in sdk dir, and my project got fatal error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Winhttp.h': No such file or directory

Does anybody know if winhttp is really supported in WinCE? And if it is, how to get right env to access winhttp.h?

Comment: Just follow the links to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms906346.aspx), bottom of the page shows the .h file to #include and the .lib file to link.  Just plain wininet.h/lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this may be a documentation error.

A full file search of my Platform Builder 5.0 installation, as well as a look through the Catalog, reveals no mention of WinHTTP anywhere - well, except for a solitary flag in an XML library (probably carried over from desktop Windows and/or kept around for compatibility).

You might consider using WinInet instead, which is supported in CE.